# SQL server sort contains result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a query in SQL Server that searching some words in some columns and sort result with number of matching words. for example in blow, order of result must be: Row2,Row3,Row1.

Search String:`w1 w2 w3`

Row1: **column1**=`w1 w4` **column2**=`w5 w6` ==> *matching words*:`w1`
Row2: **column1**=`w1 w2` **column2**=`w3 w4`  ==> *matching words:*`w1` `w2` `w3`
Row3: **column1**=`w1 w2` **column2**=`w5 w6` ==> *matching words:*`w1` `w2`
Row4: **column1**=`w5 w6` **column2**=`w7 w8 w9`

My code:  `select * from Table1 where contains((col1,col2),@search))`

Comment: where ... order by col1

Comment: thanks, but just in this example col1 have most search string and when sort with one column, priority of that column get high and i don't want this.

Comment: don't really understand what you're asking here, can you try to add some more details or a clearer example?

Comment: ok! I'm get editing Question.

Comment: You want the total number of matching words, or the strings itself?

Comment: yes, i want to sort matching rows with number of matching word.

Comment: @Micle can you give a schema of the table you are using? this is a little hard to figure out how to perform the search

Answer (score 0):

Look at [CONTAINSTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/ms189760(v=sql.120).aspx) statement, it help you sort result by matching rank.

```
create table Table1 (id int primary key identity(1,1), col1 varchar(100), col2 varchar(100));
GO
create fulltext catalog Test AS DEFAULT;
GO
create fulltext index on Table1(col1, col2) 
key index PK__Table1__3213E83FFB568640 ON Test; 
GO

insert into Table1 (col1, col2)
values
   ('w1 w4','w5 w6')
  ,('w1 w2','w3 w4')
  ,('w1 w2','w5 w6')
  ,('w5 w6','w7 w8 w9')

declare @search varchar(100) = 'w1 or w2 or w3';

select * from Table1 T
join CONTAINSTABLE(Table1, (col1,col2), @search) AS M ON T.ID = M.[KEY]
order by M.[RANK] DESC;
```

Comment: @Jamiec Maybe it will help more

Comment: Ive tried this, and for the specific example the seatch term `w1 w2 w3` errors - it must be `w1 or w2 or w3`, but then every row with a match brings back the same rank.

Comment: @Jamiec Strangely, this is my results (Id-Rank): 2 - 48, 3 - 32, 1 - 32

Comment: I get 1-48, 2-48, 3-48. Strange indeed. Neither would give the OP what they wanted though!

Comment: for me get:1-128,2-128,3-128!

Comment: Sorry, CONSTAINTABLE look like not good solution. This is link to the ranking algorithm (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142524(v=sql.105).aspx). I try calculate rank manual, but did not get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

A easy way to accomplish it:

```
;WITH 

words_to_search as (
   select 'w1' w union all   
   select 'w2' w union all   
   select 'w2' w ), 

searching as (
   select Id 
   from your_table t 
   inner join words_to_search w 
     on t.column1 + t.column2 like '%' + w.w + '%' ),

ranking_it as (
   select Id, count(*) as n
   from searching
   group by Id )

select * 
  from ranking_it r -- joining your table if you need
 order by r.n;
```

Be careful with performance, will be terrible about concat and like operation.

Comment: good, but i'm using `Full-text indexed` column and `contains` for get best performance.

Comment: @Micle, of course, you can change `like` by `contains`, like this: `contains((col1,col2),w))`.

Comment: Ive tried this and changing it to use `contains` yields the error `Incorrect syntax near 'w'.`